# Python: get arrays from nd-array list that contain specific entries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following array list

```
arr= [['Activity A', 'Activity C', 'Activity C', 'Activity B'],
 ['Activity A', 'Activity C', 'jhi50265u48lj', 'gla8vnbq94vq4'],
 ['Activity D', 'Activity E', 'Activity F', 'Activity G', 'Activity C', 'Activity B']]
```

i want only those arrays that contain all the item that start with 'Activity' eg. the output from the above list should be:

```
arrb=[['Activity A', 'Activity C', 'Activity C', 'Activity B'],
     ['Activity D', 'Activity E', 'Activity F', 'Activity G', 'Activity C', 'Activity B']]
```

I tried to do this but its escaping the item as i am checking the items individually

```
X1 = [[event for event in x1 if event.startswith('Activity')] for x1 in arr]
```

with this code i get :

```
X1= [['Activity A', 'Activity C', 'Activity C', 'Activity B'],
     ['Activity A', 'Activity C'],
     ['Activity D', 'Activity E', 'Activity F', 'Activity G', 'Activity C', 'Activity B']]
```

also i want to do it efficiently as the list can grow very big

One more thing there is another array that contain the names corresponding to these sub arrays eg:

```
names = ['p1','p2','p3']
```

so when the second array is removed it should also remove the 'p2' from names array

Comment: Please use relevant tags while tagging your question. You have tagged `arraylist` tag from java in `python` related question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in function [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
X1 = [i for i in arr if all([j.startswith('Activity') for j in i])]
```

I just used a list comprehension that checks whether each of the elements in each sub-array matched the condition you specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one line if you want to upate the names list as well.
Try this code :

```
X1 = []
for x1 in arr : 
    if x1 == [ event for event in x1 if event.startswith('Activity') ] :
        X1 += [ x1 ]
    else : 
        names.pop(arr.index(x1))
```

Output :

```
>>> print X1
[['Activity A', 'Activity C', 'Activity C', 'Activity B'], ['Activity D',    'Activity E', 'Activity F', 'Activity G', 'Activity C', 'Activity B']]
>>> print names
['p1', 'p3']
```